# View.GONE not working properly

Tags: android, xml

I have a GridView of items which i am getting from a web API. I want a "Load more" button to appear once i reach the end of gridview. It works properly until i click the button. The button is supposed to disappear without leaving space but its actually leaving the space.

I get this when i reach the end of the GridView.
[image]
When i click the load more button it disappears which is good but leaves space.
Below is my piece of code:
[image]

```
 @Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
{
    Log.v("TestInstallationTaskLst", "onScroll");
    int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
    if(lastItem==totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
    {
        loadMoreButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        loadMoreButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

 @Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if (view == loadMoreButton)
    {
        int offset = assets.size()+1;
        new DownloadTask().execute(searchText, offset, LIMIT);
        loadMoreButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Main Content View (Must be first child in the DrawerLayout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_grey_color">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <SearchView android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:queryHint="Search vehicle"/>


        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2">
        </GridView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/load_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load more"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
<!-- Navigation Drawer -->
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/gps_menu_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_bar_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@color/gps_dark_grey"/>
```

Comment: Did you set your gridview's height on match_parent?

Comment: Yeah i did but it didn't work

Comment: can you post the xml layout of your activity/fragment?

Comment: Could you please show your layout file?

Comment: i posted my xml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Using RelativeLayout

> EDITED :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Main Content View (Must be first child in the DrawerLayout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:queryHint="Search vehicle"/>


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2">
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/load_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Load more"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I tried Relative layout as well. It seems like its not working too. My SearchView disappears.

Comment: @Tee i edited my answer .Try again and replace all the xml file with mine . It worked very well for me . exactly how you want

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to the fact that you set your `layout_height` incorrectly for the `LinearLayout` elements.

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SearchView android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:queryHint="Search vehicle"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2">
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/load_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load more"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you're using `layout_weight` to set the height of the element - use `layout_height="0dp"`, and **NOT** `layout_height="match_parent"`. Additionally you had your `searchView's` height set to `match_parent` as well.

Comment: did you try to use EXACTLY those heights for every single element of your `LinearLayout`?